# Could not send command to XPrinter

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, thermal-printer

I have a problem to send command to xPrinter. I have its SDK for iOS app and follow the instruction in this framework to successfully connect my iOS app to this printer via WIFI connection.

```
NSString * ip = "IPAddress";
[manager MConnectWithHost:ip port:9100 completion: ^(BOOL result){  
}];
```

--> manager is created and connection is successfully.

But when send command by MWriteCommandWithData method of MWIFIManager class, it always print out the String, not command to printer.

Example:
I want to cut the page by prepare cmd for TscCommnand:

```
NSData *data = [TscCommand cut]
```

then send it to MWIFIManager by:

```
[manager MWriteCommandWithData:data];
```

Result: it print 'CUT' to the paper of printer, not cut the paper

The SDK I downloaded from here: https://www.xprintertech.com/sdk
it was written by Objective C and My iOS app was developed by Swift. 
I just want to implement a method to connect and print on the XPrinter (thermal-printer).

Anyone who has experience on this please advise. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do with the IP address...

Here is all you need to print in iOS:

Class printInteractionController = NSClassFromString(@"UIPrintInteractionController");

```
if ((printInteractionController != nil) && [printInteractionController isPrintingAvailable])
{
    NSURL *fileURL = document.fileURL; // Document file URL

    printInteraction = [printInteractionController sharedPrintController];

    if ([printInteractionController canPrintURL:fileURL] == YES) // Check first
    {
        UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [NSClassFromString(@"UIPrintInfo") printInfo];

        printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
        printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
        printInfo.jobName = document.fileName;

        printInteraction.printInfo = printInfo;
        printInteraction.printingItem = fileURL;
        printInteraction.showsPageRange = YES;

        if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            [printInteraction presentFromRect:button.bounds inView:button animated:YES completionHandler:
                ^(UIPrintInteractionController *pic, BOOL completed, NSError *error)
                {
                    #ifdef DEBUG
                        if ((completed == NO) && (error != nil)) NSLog(@"%s %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
                    #endif
                }
            ];
        }
        else // Presume UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone
        {
            [printInteraction presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:
                ^(UIPrintInteractionController *pic, BOOL completed, NSError *error)
                {
                    #ifdef DEBUG
                        if ((completed == NO) && (error != nil)) NSLog(@"%s %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
                    #endif
                }
            ];
        }
    }
}
```